# Autosys job shows success but failed

Tags: autosys

I've some weird situation. My autosys job status shows that it ran successfully but when I checked the logs it showed it was failed.

Is that possible ? Has anyone encountered this kind of issue ?

Comment: can u share the error msg, exit code, background of the Autosys job, like what task does it trigger ?

Comment: @Piyush, In autosys its showing exit code as "0", error message is simply a java application failed error due to some rest api issue.

Comment: what script does it trigger ? shell or java directly ?

Comment: It a Java code..

Comment: autosys marks the job status by exit code.
your script should explicitly mention user defined exit code for autosys to mark them as failed.

Comment: try to capture such a runtime, and pass "System.exit(101)" and your Autosys job should fail with 101 exit code

Answer (score 0):

Use the **-b** option in the SQLCMD.  This post gives a good explanation, and the solution worked for me... https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/77298/how-to-make-sqlcmd-return-an-errorlevel-other-than-0-when-the-sql-script-fails

Taken from the above link...

> You should use the option -b in sqlcmd.

> -b Specifies that sqlcmd exits and returns a DOS ERRORLEVEL value when an  error occurs. The value that is returned to the DOS ERRORLEVEL variable is  1 when the SQL Server error message has a severity level greater than 10;  otherwise, the value returned is 0.

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).